# How to improve/refactor this xslt?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Given the following xml :

```
<tree>
    <val>0</val>
    <tree>
        <val>1</val>
        <tree>
            <val>3</val>
        </tree>
        <tree>
            <val>4</val>
        </tree>
    </tree>
    <tree>
        <val>2</val>
        <tree>
            <val>5</val>
        </tree>
        <tree>
            <val>6</val>
        </tree>
    </tree>
</tree>
```

I need to transform it into this xml:

```
<root>0
    <frst>1
        <leaf>3</leaf>
        <leaf>4</leaf>
    </frst>
    <second>2
        <leaf>5</leaf>
        <leaf>6</leaf>
    </second>
</root>
```

---

This is my attempt that gives the same result, I recently started learning XSLT i'm not sure what other option I have, can this be improved or done in another way ?
Thank you for your help

This is my attempt :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/tree">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="val">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tree">
        <xsl:choose>
            <!--  IF HAS CHILDREN -->
            <xsl:when test="child::tree">
                <xsl:if test="(count(preceding-sibling::tree)+1) = 1">
                    <frst>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </frst>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="(count(preceding-sibling::tree)+1) = 2">
                    <second>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </second>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <!--  ELSE IS A LEAF  -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <leaf>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </leaf>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

test test

Comment: A problem with this kind of question is that one example does not constitute a statement of requirements. What other inputs might be encountered?

Answer (score 0):

I would think the conditions can be written in match patterns:

```
  <xsl:template match="tree[tree][1]">
    <frst>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </frst>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="tree[tree][2]">
    <second>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </second>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="tree[not(tree)]">
    <leaf>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </leaf>
  </xsl:template>
```

although I guess your current code doesn't process the third/fourth/fifth.. `tree` children so an additional `<xsl:template match="tree[tree][position() > 2]"/>` might be necessary.

Comment: Ohh it's much cleaner and shorter, but there is an issue where <root> becomes <frst> too. I've been trying to experiment with it but I can't make it work, is it possible to say : match tree with two tree children only then do <root> apply template...

Comment: My suggestion implied to keep the template matching `/tree` and also the one matching `val` from your code, sorry for not spelling that out, I just tried to show the parts I would refactor.

Comment: Ah yes, I did it but it's "Ambiguous rule match for /tree
Matches both "tree[tree][1]"

Comment: @gleetchi, ah, yes, I think you need to give the template for an explicitly higher priority than the default ones with e.g. `match="/tree" priority="5"`.